# xmldb_field Moodle change column type

Tags: php, database, postgresql, moodle

I'm trying to change the column type from a `character varying (10)` to that of a date.

I can run it individually like so:

```
ALTER TABLE "tbl_name" ALTER "col_name" TYPE timestamp USING (col_name ::timestamp);
```

But after throwing this into the upgrade.php script, it barfs on me and requires the `USING` clause which I can't seem to get to work.  Or if there even is a way...

Here's my upgrade.php script:

```
$table = new xmldb_table('tbl_name');
$field = new xmldb_field('col_name', XMLDB_TYPE_DATETIME);
if ($dbman->field_exists($table, $field)) {
    $dbman->change_field_notnull($table, $field);
}
```

When logging into the Moodle admin and running the update, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "col_name" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone HINT: You might need to specify "USING col_name::timestamp without time zone".
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the Moodle docs (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_column_types) you should avoid using datetime fields - all timestamps in Moodle are declared as integer(10).

If you're using the XMLDB Editor built into Moodle to generate your database table definitions (and you really should do that), then it does not give the option of using the datetime field type.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm definitely a Moodle noob, and literally found that same page about 10 minutes after posting that ^^ above.  Also... I discovered / remembered / smacked my forward when it dawned on me that the application is basically taking all data out of the DB and putting into JSON right away before doing anything with it.  So really... it doesn't matter in the end.  What did (ultimately) matter was just formatting the date to yyyy-mm-dd away from the d-m-yy that the original data was stored as.  That was my 'Doh!! moment of that day...  :-/